# Is there any trick to inverting this $3 \times 3$ function matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The matrix in question is:
$$A(t) = \begin{bmatrix} e^{t} & e^{-t} & e^{2t} \\ 
e^{t} & -e^{t} & 2e^{2t} \\
e^{t} & e^{-t} & 4e^{2t}
\end{bmatrix}$$
The only simplification I can see is to write $A(t)$ as
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 2\\
1 & 1 & 4\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix} e^t & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{-t} & 0\\
0 & 0 & e^{2t}\end{bmatrix}$$
And then invert each matrix (for the left matrix, I can only see using the usual algorithm involving row reduction), reverse the order, and multiply.

Is there anything I'm missing here that would make it easier to find $A^{-1}(t)$?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just apply the usual algorithm to the original matrix.... I’m assuming you have a typo and the center entry should be $-e^{-t}$?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Right. I am just wondering if there is some trick to invert this particular matrix, since it has a regular structure.

Comment: Also are you sure about the $(2,3)$ entry?  If it were $2e^{2t}$ instead then you have a Wronskian matrix...

Comment: The inverse of your integer matrix is $1/6*(6,3,-3//2,-3,1//-2,0,2)$. The inverse of the diagonal matrix is easy. So mutliply them together the other way round. (Edited for the new matrix.)

Comment: @user10354138 My bad, indeed it is $2e^{2t}$! Is there an easy way to invert Wronskian matrices?

Comment: Wronskian matrices have no reason to be simpler to invert.

Comment: Well, you should know how to [invert a Vandermonde matrix](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix).